# How to link a settings bundle page in iOS 8 storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I'm fairly new to iOS programming in general, but I was curious in how to implement the settings bundle. All the implementation guides I see say to create the settings bundle file, and then the tutorials just magically skip to having the iPhone screen already on the settings page.

My question is, how do I put a put a link to the settings bundle page? Maybe my conceptual understanding of iOS programming is very misconstrued but I just can't quite get how to make the pages link.

I was trying to do this in a single-view application, by the way, which I feel may be a tremendous mistake in the way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an IBAction method in your view controller to connect to one of your buttons that will open the Settings app.

The basic code that you would want for this in your IBAction is:

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
```

Relevant links:

- [Apple sample code on how to do this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AppPrefs/Introduction/Intro.html)
- [Information on IBAction](http://nshipster.com/ibaction-iboutlet-iboutletcollection/)